# SceneKit editor set custom class for node

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, scenekit

In the SpriteKit editor, I can assign a custom class to an SKNode, like so:

[image]

However,  I can't seem to find the equivalent functionality in the SceneKit editor. Does it even exist? And if I can't set a custom class for an SCNNode, is there a reason the feature isn't there, or has the Xcode team just not gotten around to it? (In other words, should I file a radar?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it in the scene editor. And you probably shouldn't do it at all. You'll have to implement your own serialization code (so that `SCNScene` loading works correctly). And all of the methods for searching nodes (by name, hit test, within a volume) return `SCNNode`, so you'll be forever casting your results.

Per Apple developers, `SCNScene` is not meant to be subclassed, and I think that extends to `SCNNode`. Write an extension instead.

See:

- [Trouble subclassing SCNScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534743/trouble-subclassing-scnscene)
- [Subclassing SCNNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616913/subclassing-scnnode)
- [Subclassing SCNScene and SceneKit Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881677/subclassing-scnscene-and-scenekit-editor)

Comment: Why is a SCNNode not meant to be subclassed ? Who says that, Apple ? Where can we read about best practices then ?

Comment: I don't think I can add anything to the three SO questions I linked to. If you think you need to subclass it, that deserves a separate question that describes what you really want to do.

Comment: "You can't do it in the scene editor."  Is that still the case?  it's really bizarre.