# How to add a primitive with a class in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

Making a class in SceneKit is important. However, I cannot get it to work.

Here is my class code

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit

class Ship: SCNNode {
    override init(){
        super.init()

    let box = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)

    let node = SCNNode(geometry: box)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")


  }
}
```

And here is my code in the ViewController (I am using ARKit)

```
   let tempShip = Ship()
    tempShip.position = SCNVector3(0.1,0.1,0.1)

    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(tempShip)
```

I think I am missing something basic.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have not created an `SCNScene` and added it to your view. At least there's no sign of that in the code you posted. You need to have something like

```
sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
```

or create it using one of `SCNScene`'s `init` methods.

Then you'll have a scene you can hang your node on. Don't forget to add lighting and camera.

Also: don't subclass `SCNNode`. Use an extension instead. If you subclass `SCNNode` or `SCNScene` you can't use the Xcode Scene Editor. See [SceneKit editor set custom class for node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921638/scenekit-editor-set-custom-class-for-node/44936535#44936535).

Answer (score 1):

You should be seeing a warning that your node variable is not being used, you need to set the geometry on the node. Change your init method to this:

```
override init(){
    super.init()
    let box = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
    self.geometry = box
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An SCNView's scene property is an optional. Change the last line to:

```
guard let scene = sceneView.scene else { return }
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(tempShip)
```

Comment: I couldn't get the gaurd let statement to work. Is there another way we can do this?

Comment: If you are using an `ARSCNView` from ARKit the `scene` property is **not** optional.